# Is it possible to ripple edit Adobe Premier?

Tags: premiere, editing, adobe, vegas-pro

Prior to using Adobe Premier, I used Sony Vegas as my primary video editing software. While using it, I have gotten accustomed to using a feature called ripple editing. When enabled, it allowed you to make changes to the video timeline such as deleting clips and it would snap the remaining video forward. The ripple effected all of the tracks to ensure the remaining part of the video is not out of sync. Is there an easy way to achieve this with Adobe Premier?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Ripple Edit Tool. [See here](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/panels.html) (*Tools panel and Options panel* section)

Comment: Thank you for that... I did run into it and was wondering what its purpose was. Essentially, it is to shorten a clip from one end and have the following clips collapse into take up the room. Now the problem that I am facing is that I work with a lot of long clips (often have video with a single shot) that need to be edited into multiple smaller clips. In vegas, I would use the splice tool to mark the start and end of a cut and delete the clip. The remaining parts will ripple down to join the beginning of the cut. How can I achieve this with premier?

Comment: to ripple-trim the start of a clip put the playhead where you want the clip to start and hit `q`. To do the same for the end of the clip, hit `w`. To ripple-delete a clip select it and use `shift+delete`.

Comment: @stib - Sorry for the late response... is there a shortcut for the razor tool? I think shift+delete does what I want, but I need to easily make cuts at the location of the played head.

Comment: @ShadowZzz *CTRL+K* to cut the clip at the playhead. Hold *Shift* in addition to cut all clips in all tracks at the playhead position. Or press *C* to select the Razor Tool

Comment: @MoritzLost - Thank You! That's exactly what I was looking for...